# receive packets and forward them on different port

Tags: java, network-programming

Is there some kind of tool (best would be in Java) that is capable of receiving packets on specific ports, and forward them on another one? Example:

Incoming Syslog on port 514 UDP --> Forward to new destination on port 1514 UDP.

Traffic is no video stream or anything, just some syslog data.

Thanks

Comment: on which platform you are working? windows, linux?

Comment: Are you asking for a library? Are you trying to implement it?

Comment: If you're looking for a TCP proxy: http://en.dfr.ch/free-software/java-tcp-proxy For UDP this might work: https://github.com/guardianproject/Orlib/blob/master/src/net/sourceforge/jsocks/socks/UDPRelayServer.java

Comment: sorry for the unclear description - it shall be a java application for commandline (on linux) - alredy got it up and running :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to do it in user-space application (if you are not interested in that data). In linux you can use iptables for that purpose. Run this command.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport $srcPortNumber -j REDIRECT --to-port $dstPortNumber
```

You might need to start the iptables service if it is not running already. Check your linux distribution and see how to check the status or start iptables service in that distribution.

If you are using windows then you might need to see [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: "Not feasible" is perhaps too strong.  Not advisable is definitely true.  A kernel-space solution is going to be faster, and less prone to dropping packets.

Comment: I did it with a DatagramSocket listening to a port, and opening a handler thread which is sending the packet to another port when something arrives. I couldn't "overload" the thing to get an packet dropped for now